# React - Populate UserManagerSettings Using External Configuration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Hopefully someone can help, the issue I am having is, there is a typescript file named `user-manager.ts` this creates the redux-oidc `userManager` using the `UserManagerSettings` overload, however the `userManager` is always consutructed before the configuration is loaded, so the `userManagerSettings` never gets set correctly, and because this is done immediately, when the application loads, it means that when the `userManager` is used in any of the other components it fails.

This configuration is retrieved by an API get request that surfaces configuration from an *appsettings.json* file, which is transformed when deployed. The API action returns this configuration as json and is then put into a configuration type.  We did this because we did not want to load in environment specific configuration, as configuration is handled in Octopus Deploy when deployed via kubernetes.

Is there a way we can ensure the configuration is loaded before the `userManager` is created, using the same method?

Thanks,

user-manager.ts

```
import { UserManagerSettings } from 'oidc-client';
import { createUserManager } from 'redux-oidc';
import config from './config/configuration';

const userManagerConfig: UserManagerSettings = {
 authority: config.authority,
 client_id: config.clientId,
 redirect_uri: config.redirectUri,
 silent_redirect_uri: config.silentRedirectUri,
 post_logout_redirect_uri: config.postLogoutRedirectUri,
 response_type: 'id_token token',
 scope: 'openid profile IdentityServerApi',
 automaticSilentRenew: true,
 filterProtocolClaims: true,
 loadUserInfo: true,
 monitorSession: true
};

const userManager = createUserManager(userManagerConfig);

export default userManager;
```

configuration.ts

```
import Axios from 'axios';

var config: IConfiguration = {
    authority: '',
    clientId: '',
    redirectUri: '',
    silentRedirectUri: '',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: ''
};

export default config;

export interface IConfiguration {
    authority: string;
    clientId: string;
    redirectUri: string;
    silentRedirectUri: string;
    postLogoutRedirectUri: string;
}

function populateConfiguration(): Promise<IConfiguration> {
    return Axios.get<IConfiguration>('/config')
        .then(response => {
            return copyValuesToLocalConfig(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Promise.reject();
        });
    }

function copyValuesToLocalConfig(configuration: IConfiguration): IConfiguration {
    config = Object.assign(config, configuration);
    return config;
}

export { populateConfiguration };
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by changing the `user-manager` to be a class with a static instance that populates the `UserManagerSettings` and creates the `usermanager` in the constructor. I then created a new instance of the class, before it was required, but when I knew the configuration has been successfully loaded. I then reused this instance in the components that required it.

```
import { UserManagerSettings, UserManager } from 'oidc-client';
import { createUserManager } from 'redux-oidc';
import config from './config/configuration';

export class UserDetails {
    public static userManager: UserManager;
    private static userManagerConfig: UserManagerSettings;

    constructor() {
        UserDetails.userManagerConfig = {
            authority: config.authority,
            client_id: config.clientId,
            redirect_uri: config.redirectUri,
            silent_redirect_uri: config.silentRedirectUri,
            post_logout_redirect_uri: config.postLogoutRedirectUri,
            response_type: 'id_token token',
            scope: 'openid profile IdentityServerApi',
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            filterProtocolClaims: true,
            loadUserInfo: true,
            monitorSession: true
       };
        UserDetails.userManager = createUserManager(UserDetails.userManagerConfig);
    }
}
```

This is where the usermanager is used.

```
  const configureStore = (history: History) => {
  const allReducers = rootReducer(history);
  const userDetails = new UserDetails(); //We know the config is loaded at this point because it is rendered in a parent component.
  const oidcMiddleware = createOidcMiddleware(UserDetails.userManager);

  const store = createStore(allReducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk, oidcMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history))));
  loadUser(store, UserDetails.userManager);

  return store;
};
```

Comment: hi David, would you mind to share your code as I am facing the same issue and I dont see how your suggested answer work by pulling config from API? thank you

Comment: We found a better approach in the end, using this package https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env allowing the variables to be populated at runtime & not compile time :)

Comment: @DavidB I have the same scenario of loading the config from API and load into redux-store. And then use that in userManagerSettings. I don't need it as env variables. If you have the code which you mentioned in the answer, kindly share. I want do the API call and load the values while the loadUser is called